# Redis: Is it possible to get values without using a set?

Tags: nosql, redis

In my app, I set my users information like:

```
set users:alex:age 30
set users:alex:heigth 1.8
set users:sly:age 32
set users:sly:heigth 1.95
```

Is there a way to get the list of users (alex, sly) without using a Set Or do I need to use a Set like:

```
sadd users users:alex
sadd users users:sly
```

and get the users with

```
smembers users
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a set is the proper way to do it. You can also use [keys users:*:age](http://redis.io/commands/keys) to get all users, but that would be much slower.

Also, instead of using users:*:age, users:*:height, you should use a hash in users: with "age" and "height" as keys.